# output row base on index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame containing toy sales numbers and I'm looking for help on two things:

1. Is it possible to combine the two line of code below into one.
2. Is it possible to print out entire row base on the index_num that is outputted?

---

```
max = Toy['salenum'].max()
index_num = Toy[Toy['inv_change'] == max].index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 1st question, you can do:

```
index_num = Toy.loc[Toy['inv_change']==Toy['salenum'].max()].index.tolist()
```

To print out the rows with the index_num, you can do:

```
Toy.loc[index_num]
```